# Making Rails loop over an element to represent items in my table

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am building a Rails app, and I am using a hexagonal grid to show links to its blog posts as an image hexagon for each post. For clarity, here's what that looks like with static posts:

```
 <ul id="hexGrid">
            <li class="hex">
                <a class="hexIn" href="contact">
                    <img src="https://structurepoint.files.wordpress.com/2014/09/wp_20140804_041.jpg" alt="" />
                    <h1>This is a title</h1>
                    <p>Some sample text about the article this hexagon leads to</p>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="hex">
                <a class="hexIn" href="#">
                    <img src="https://structurepoint.files.wordpress.com/2014/09/wp_20140804_041.jpg" alt="" />
                    <h1>This is a title</h1>
                    <p>Some sample text about the article this hexagon leads to</p>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="hex">
                <a class="hexIn" href="#">
                    <img src="https://structurepoint.files.wordpress.com/2014/09/wp_20140804_041.jpg" alt="" />
                    <h1>This is a title</h1>
                    <p>Some sample text about the article this hexagon leads to</p>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

To see the full code for it, here's [the JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p9810xdj/).

Here's the problem. I need to make the hexagons dynamic, and I want it to generate one for each of them in my `Post` table. To do that, I tried to iterate like so:

```
 <ul id="hexGrid">
            <li class="hex">
                <a class="hexIn" href="#">
                    <% @posts.each do |post| %>
                        <%= image_tag("http://www.fearthewave.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/bevo-768x410.png", :alt => "rss feed") %>
                        <h1><%= post.title %></h1>
                    <p><%= post.category %></p>
                    <% end %>
                </a>
            </li>
</ul>
```

Even though in my controller, I am setting `@posts = Post.all` and there are five posts in the database, the code above is only generating one hexagon for a post. I want the view to render 5 of them.

Is it possible to make the hexagon `<li>` dynamic?

### Possible Questions

1. *There is a static image link in the iteration, why did you do that?* I put that image link in as a placeholder. I haven't installed the Paperclip gem yet -- I want it to produce 5 hexagons, and it's fine that it uses a static image now. In the future, this will link to the image associated with the post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're doing the loop in the wrong place:

```
<ul id="hexGrid">
  <% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <li class="hex">
    <a class="hexIn" href="#">
      <%= image_tag("http://www.fearthewave.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/bevo-768x410.png", :alt => "rss feed") %>
      <h1><%= post.title %></h1>
      <p><%= post.category %></p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```